# 'set' object has no attribute 'get' CSV (in praw)

Tags: python, csv, praw, replit

This code is supposed to get some information about a post like title, upvotes etc. And then write it in a CSV file. But when is run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 71, in <module>
    writer.writerow(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/csv.py", line 154, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/csv.py", line 151, in <genexpr>
    return (rowdict.get(key, self.restval) for key in self.fieldnames)
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'get'
```

And this is the code:

```
    import praw
    import random
    import time
    import csv
    #from keep_Aliv import keep_alive
    
    username = "XXXXXX"
    
    #keep_alive()
    
    print('AAAAAAA')
    
    reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id="XXXXXX",
                         client_secret="XXXXXX",
                         user_agent="bot",
                         username=username,
                         password='XXXXXX')
    
    
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit('all')
    
   with open('pdata.csv', 'a') as f:
    headers = [
        'ID', 'Date_utc', 'Upvotes', 'Number of Comments', 'Subthread name'
    ]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f,
                            fieldnames=headers,
                            extrasaction='ignore',
                            dialect='excel')
    writer.writeheader()
    for post in subreddit.stream.submissions():
        #print(post.title)
        
        data = {
                "ID": post.id,
                "Date_utc": post.created_utc,
                "Upvotes": post.ups,
                "Number of comments": post.num_comments,
                "Subthread name": post.title,
                }
        writer.writerow(data)
        print(data)
```

ok, so how am I supposed to fix this? pls tell if some other information is required.

Thanks :)

(The main problem is now fixed and the compiler is not throwing an error now, but on the other hand the program isn't writing anything in the csv file. There isn't any error detected by the compiler but it's still not doing what it's supposed to. How do I fix that? btw the code in the post the working code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a dict writer, which accepts dicts. You are passing a string to it.

You should construct a dict, and write that:

```
data = {
    "ID": post,
    "Date_utc": post.created_utc,
    "Upvotes": post.ups,
    "Number of comments": post.num_comments,
    "Subthread name": post.title,
}
writer.writerow(data)
```

For more information how to use the dictwriter you can go here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/writing-csv-files

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution and now its kinda working. Now it doesn't throw an error but it isn't appending anything in the csv file. To test whether if it's even working or not I added a print statement and it printed everything it was supposed to that so in the correct format. I thought that it was because of multiple lines of data and new data coming every minute. So I tried changing ```writerow(data)``` to ```writerows(data)``` and it threw the same error that it was giving before. I updated the code in the main post if that is required and what should I do now? Thanks

Comment: I suspect that it fails on `"ID": post`, there  you are writing a whole post object, while you mean to write something like `"ID": post.id` i assume.

Comment: After doing that it writes the alphabet 'e' in the CSV file? Does that stand for error cuz there is no error in the compiler?

Comment: oops, the program wasn't writing the word e it was just written by me by mistake. But the program is still now writing the data in the csv file.

Comment: So it works as expected now?

Comment: Yup, just gave it a check and it's now writing all the data. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

`data` does not appear to be in the correct format:

Try the following:

```py
data = {
    'ID' : post, 
    'Date_utc' : post.created_utc, 
    'Upvotes' : post.ups,
    'Number of comments' : post.num_comments,
    'Subthread name' : post.title
}
```

Note: when using a [dictwriter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), you should also open you file with the `newline` parameter as follows:

```
with open('pdata.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
```

This avoids extra newlines in the output.